# Can anyone explain the configuring steps in Process section if TFS 2013 new build definition?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create New build Definition for my Team project. I am not able to understand the Workspace and Process sections. Please explain the steps to configure parameters in Process sections so that Build will be sucessfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set the solution to build in the process tab. That will get you started.